# How to horizontalize react js component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I created app to map all card components on a page. But components are shown vertically. I need to show 3 components per row. How can I show it like that? Here is my code.

```
 const[item, setItem] = useState([]);

function addItem(newItem){ //This addItem Part is working.
    setItem(prevItems =>{
        return [...prevItems, newItem]
    });
}

return(<div className="container">
        <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg-4" style={{cursor: "pointer"}}>
            <AddCard />
        </div>

        <div style={{cursor: "pointer"}}>

            {item.map((items, index)=>{
                return(
                    <div className="col-lg-4" >
                        <ItemCard
                            key={index}
                            id={index}
                            title={items.title}
                            description={items.description}
                        />
                    </div>
                )
        })}
        </div>

        </div>)
```

Comment: This sounds like a question about CSS, not really about React. I see some classes in your code like `col-lg-4` – I assume this comes from some CSS framework you are using. It may be necessary for us to know which framework that is – for example, [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) or [Semantic UI](https://semantic-ui.com/).

Comment: I'm using react-boostrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use display:"flex" on the container**

```js
 const[item, setItem] = useState([]);

function addItem(newItem){ //This addItem Part is working.
    setItem(prevItems =>{
        return [...prevItems, newItem]
    });
}

return(<div className="container">
        <div className="row">
        <div className="col-lg-4" style={{cursor: "pointer"}}>
            <AddCard />
        </div>

        <div style={{cursor: "pointer", display:"flex"}}>

            {item.map((items, index)=>{
                return(
                    <div className="col-lg-4" >
                        <ItemCard
                            key={index}
                            id={index}
                            title={items.title}
                            description={items.description}
                        />
                    </div>
                )
        })}
        </div>

        </div>)
```

Comment: I need to show 3 components per row. But If I use 'flex' It will show all components as a line.

Comment: So you should try:  display: "grid", grid-template-columns: "1fr 1fr 1fr"

Comment: the syntax in react is different, try add  class to the container and add this with css: 

.some-container-class{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

By the way you can change the '1fr' to any size you want like '300px'

Answer (score 0):

Use flexboxes, as React lets you create components, so we can style them just like HTML elements with flexboxes.

Example :

```css
.flexbox-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-container">
    <div>Element1</div>
    <div>Element2</div>
    <div>Element3</div>
</div>
```